# Rails 4 + Rspec: DRY test for custom authentication with REST API's parent controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rest, authentication, rspec

I am building a REST API and have an `Api::ApiController` that is the parent of the resource's controller and holds the authentication code so that multiple resources can inherit the authentication functionality. This controller does not have any actions itself, so how can I test it with rspec? I can't send any `GET` requests to it and I'd like to keep the tests as DRY as the actual implementation.

```
class Api::V1::ApiController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :authenticate

  protected
  def authenticate
    request_key = request.headers['X-Api-Key']
    master_key  = Rails.application.secrets.something['api_key']

    unless secure_compare(request_key, master_key)
      head status: 401
      return false
    end
  end

  # extracted from ActiveSupport::MessageVerifier#secure_compare
  def secure_compare(a, b)
    return false unless a.bytesize == b.bytesize

    l = a.unpack "C#{a.bytesize}"

    res = 0
    b.each_byte { |byte| res |= byte ^ l.shift }
    res == 0
  end
end


# app/controllers/api/v1/resources_controller.rb
class Api::V1::ResourcesController < Api::ApiController
  def index
    ..
  end

  # etc etc
end

# spec/controllers/api/v1/resources_controller_spec.rb
  context 'Api::ApiController#authenticate' do 
    describe 'bad key' do
      before { request.headers['X-API-KEY'] = 'xyz' }

      it 'prevents unauthorized access' do 
        get 'index', format: :json
        expect(response.status).to eq 401
      end
    end

    describe 'good key' do 
      before { request.headers['X-API-KEY'] = Rails.application.secrets.something['api_key'] }

      it 'grants access' do 
        get 'index', format: :json
        expect(response.status).to eq 200
      end
    end
  end
```

I have tests in my resource's controller spec file for the `#authenticate` method above, but it doesn't feel right to have them there because a) that method is part of `Api::ApiController`, not `Api::ResourceController`, and because ideally I would need to validate the authentication in every resource's controller.

Do I need to add an action (something like `index` or `test`) as well as the necessary route for this controller just to do the authentication test?

Comment: I don't remember but I'm marking max's answer as correct since there's not really a "solution" and that one seems sensible. It's probably what I went with!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can setup an abstract controller which inherits your ApiController (see [Test a base (abstract) controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15620684/test-a-base-abstract-controller)) but I think you may be going at it the wrong way.

Rather than subclassing you could place your authentication logic in a concern or helper which is then included.

The advantage being that you can call your methods directly in a test rather than trying to setup a request. Controller specs can be finicky when it comes to auth since they do not have the session and env of an actual request.

I would then add a functional test to the first controller which implements the authentication to test the integration.